# What is the default MAXDEPTH value in an Orient TRAVERSE statement?

Tags: orientdb, orientdb2.2

I'm assuming the MAXDEPTH in a TRAVERSE is -1 but the documentation doesn't actually specify it.

http://orientdb.com/docs/master/SQL-Traverse.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default MAXDEPTH is -1 (unlimited traversal)